How to display Wavegen output along with the scope, in AD2 using Waveforms?
I have an Analog Discovery 2, and am using it to study a couple of analog filters. I've created a sine signal from the Wavegen tool, and am probing the output on both the Oscilloscope channels.
From the attached screenshot, it seems that I should be able to see the "W1" signal on this graph. However, I cannot check the box corresponding to Wavegen 1 on the right panel. When I click it, it doesn't accept my click. How do I proceed?

